# Webservice path in jquery /json

Tags: jquery, json, web-services

When I give my local path in Jquery it is working.Eg. url: "/LP18WS.asmx/AuthonticateUser",
But when I change it to online path 
Eg. url: "http://lp18mobile.azurewebsites.net/LP18WS.asmx/AuthonticateUser"
What I need to do to make it working. 
Is ther anything we need to do with namespace 
because if you open web service http://lp18mobile.azurewebsites.net/LP18WS.asmx 
at the bottom, you can see some message about namespace of webservice.

Answer (score 0):

```
   you need to Set crossDomain Property to true to make a Cross domain call.

jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:'',
            crossDomain :true,
            url: 'http://lp18mobile.azurewebsites.net/LP18WS.asmx/AuthonticateUser',
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error in Save Data: " + textStatus);
            }
        });  

      Please See below Link For more Information:
      http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
```

Comment: `crossDomain :true` is good for a very limited set of circumstances and most probably not in this case, with `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: for this you use JsonP datatype.

Comment: Possibly, though there's more to do than just changing `dataType: 'json'` to `dataType: 'jsonp'`.

Comment: Thanks, we did that but still not working
$.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
               url: "http://lp18mobile.azurewebsites.net/LP18WS.asmx/AuthonticateUser",
                //url: "/LP18WS.asmx/AuthonticateUser",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {},
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg.d == "Success") {
                    }
                },
            });
        }

Comment: please check that crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" is define in webservice project config or not

Comment: More info Please check link.                                                                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586328/consuming-a-wcf-service-in-jquery-via-ajax-call-in-a-different-project-cross-do

Comment: yes crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" in web.config.
<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>