# JQUERY AJAX WITH WCF REST BASED RESPONSE IN JSON

Tags: json, jquery, wcf-rest

I have created an REST BASED WCF where the ResponseFormat is in Json. I call this wcf using jquery ajax from a web page.Everything is working fine. i deployed the wcf service in IIS 7.5 as an separate website in port 8014. i deployed the wcf calling client that is the page containing jquery ajax call for wcf as an separate website in port 8018. now when i try to access the Rest based wcf i get the error as "Service Call Failed:0". I use VS2008 Framwork 3.5 for development.

### WCFREST Code:

**IService1:**

```
   [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetProvinceREST/{Country}",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        string[] GetProvinceREST(string Country);
```

**Service1:**

```
 public string[] GetProvinceREST(string Country)
        {
            string[] str = new string[3];
            str[0]= "hi";
            str[1]= "how";
            str[2]= "are";
            return str;
        }
```

---

**Jquery Ajax call code:**

```
 function CountryProvinceWCFREST() {debugger;
            varType = "GET";
            varUrl = "http://localhost:8014/Service1.svc/GetProvinceREST/" + $('#ddlCountry').val();
            varContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            varDataType = "json";
            varProcessData = false;
            CallService();
        }


 function CallService() {
            $.ajax({
                type: varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                url: varUrl, // Location of the service
                data: varData, //Data sent to server
                contentType: varContentType, // content type sent to server
                dataType: varDataType, //Expected data format from server
                processdata: varProcessData, //True or False
                success: function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
                    ServiceSucceeded(msg);
                },
                error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
            });
        }


var ProvinceDDL = document.getElementById("ddlProvince");
          for (j = ProvinceDDL.options.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) { ProvinceDDL.remove(j); }
            var resultObject = null;
if (varType == "GET") { resultObject = result; }
 for (i = 0; i < resultObject.length; i++) {
                    var opt = document.createElement("option"); opt.text = resultObject[i];
                    ProvinceDDL.options.add(opt)
                }

  <input type="button" value="Invoke" id="Button2" onclick="CountryProvinceWCFREST();" />
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a cross-domain call, meaning the service is hosted is on some different domain. You might want to use JSONP.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586328/consuming-a-wcf-service-in-jquery-via-ajax-call-in-a-different-project-cross-do) answer might help you further.

Comment: Hi but i have hosted my wcf service and wcf client in the same machine in IIS as an separate site both are written in asp.net C#. can you pls brief what is cross domain in layman style? also <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings> crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" attribute cannot be added in VS2008 with .net framework 3.5 webconfig. can u pls help me on this